# Баги отображения окна tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, macos

На mac OS Monterey 12.0.1 наблюдается некорректное отображение окна tkinter. Если запустить тестовое окно через python3 -m tkinter, то вывод будет следующий (смотрите фото). На предыдущей версии mac OS Big Sur корректное отображение наблюдалось только при включении светлой темы в системе. Может кто-то знает как решить такую проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что не так с окном?

Comment: Фон черный. Там должна быть надпись (Label). И фон должен быть белым

Comment: Имеет смысл написать автору библиотеки [CustomText](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter), которую вы похоже используете.